# How much should a child user control know of it's parent (Canvas)?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, user-controls

If you have a parent page - more like a canvas - with side action menus, when clicked the canvas is clear and a new child custom control is added. In this kind of scenario, should the child control handle it's responsibility or delegate it to the parent? How much should the child know of the parent and how much should the parent know of the child? Finally, which of these two controls should have a reference of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A child control should know nothing about it's parent control.

The parent can pass data to it in construction and on method calls and get receive data back via events and return types.